# How can I change anchor to Anchor.center in SpriteComponent in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm trying to change my object(Horse()) anchor point to Anchor.center in the creation of the object. But I wasn't able to. If I change it inside FlameGame using horse.anchor = Anchor.center it works but I want to create it with Anchor.center.

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';

class Horse extends SpriteComponent {
  final String name;
  static const double spriteSize = 64;

  @override
  set anchor(Anchor anchor) {
    super.anchor = Anchor.center;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('$name.jpg');
  }

  Horse(this.name) : super(size: Vector2.all(spriteSize));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the anchor directly to the super constructor:

```dart
import 'package:flame/components.dart';

class Horse extends SpriteComponent {
  Horse(this.name) : super(size: Vector2.all(spriteSize), anchor: Anchor.center);

  final String name;
  static const double spriteSize = 64;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('$name.jpg');
  }
}
```

If you don't want to extend `SpriteComponent` you can also do this:

```dart
final sprite = await loadSprite('horse.jpg');
final spriteSize = 64;

final component = SpriteComponent(
  sprite: sprite,
  size: Vector2.all(spriteSize),
  anchor: Anchor.center,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this and it now works but I don't think this is the ideal solution so I still want your answers pls

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';

class Horse extends SpriteComponent {
  final String name;
  static const double spriteSize = 64;

  anchorChange() {
    super.anchor = Anchor.center;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('$name.jpg');
    anchorChange();
  }

  Horse(this.name) : super(size: Vector2.all(spriteSize));
}
```